# The structure of "Even if China and America stop short of conﬂict, blabla......"

Tags: adverbs, prepositional-phrases

What is the structure of "*stop short of conflict*"?
Is it "*stop + short of conflict*" or "*stop short + of conflict*"?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, "short" is an adverb, modifying the verb "stop" (and [stop short](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stop+short) is itself an idiom), while "of conflict" is an [adverbial prepositional phrase](https://www.infoplease.com/language-arts/grammar-and-spelling/phrases-prepositional-phrases-big-daddy-phrases) modifying "short."